# Как спарсить json на python?

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

Есть код, который авторизуется на сайте, после чего я хотел бы забирать информацию, но сайт мне ее не отдает, покопавшись в запросах, я нашел json, думаю скопирую ссылку на него, но не тут то было, в ссылке есть место(sesskey), которое меняется с каждой авторизацией и из-за этого, перейдя в новой вкладе по этой ссылке выводится ошибка, как мне быть в данной ситуации, я хочу забрать этот json, но у меня не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
user_info = passwrd
login = user_info[0]
password = user_info[1]
session = requests.Session()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
headers = {
     'User-Agent': user.random
        }

response = session.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
login_token = soup.find('input', {'name': "logintoken"})['value']

data = {
        "logintoken": login_token,
        "username": login,
        "password": password
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)

profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/lib/ajax/service.php? 
sesskey=Rs62OJwrPr&info=core_calendar_get_action_events_by_timesort'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup1)
```

Comment: Так спарсить или открыть по ссылке? Не очень понятно

Comment: Чтобы спарсить нужна ссылка, ссылка меняется с каждой авторизацией. Я поискал, такой же sesskey есть в html, я беру его с помощью кода, но он все равно выдает ошибку:
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
soup2 = soup1.select_one('.logininfo')
soup3 =str(soup2).split('=')[-1].split('"')[0]
profile_info1 = f'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey={soup3}&info=core_calendar_get_action_events_by_timesort'
profile_response1 = session.get(profile_info1)
soup11 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response1.text, 'lxml')
print(soup11)